# Optimizing Chat Ordering in a Rails + Postgres - last_message_at vs. Grouping Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm currently working on a chat feature for a web application. Our tech stack includes Ruby on Rails for the backend, GraphQL for the API layer, and Next.js for the frontend.

We have two relevant tables in our database:

| **Chats** |
| --- |
| id |
| creator_id |
| created_at |
| updated_at |
| title |
| last_message_at |

| **Chat_messages** |
| --- |
| id |
| chat_id |
| user_id |
| text |
| created_at |
| updated_at |

My goal is to fetch the chats on the client side **in an order determined by the most recent activity** (i.e., the most recent message in each chat).

My current approach is to add a `last_message_at` field to the Chats table that gets updated every time a new message is sent. This way, we can order the chats by this field and get the desired ordering.

My colleague is against adding an extra column. He proposes using a grouping query between the two tables to get the same result.

I'd love to hear your thoughts on these approaches. Is it more efficient to add the `last_message_at` column and update it on each new message, or should we use a grouping query to sort the chats by the latest message?

What are the potential performance implications, especially with regard to scalability

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just check the `created_at` column of a given chat? The column describes that a message was sent and saved to the DB (or the other way round). So for example you have a chat with the `id: 1`, you just query all chat messages that have `chat_id: 1` and order them created_at desc:
`ChatMessage.where(chat_id: 1).order(created_at: :desc)`. If you want to do it in SQL, you can use:
`SELECT * FROM "chat_messages" WHERE chat_id = 1 ORDER BY created_at desc`.

Maybe I get the question wrong and a chat_message is not necessarily send once it is created.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! In this case, we were looking to get the chats in order, not their most recent message ie ```SELECT cm.chat_id, cm.max_created_at, ch.*
FROM (
    SELECT chat_id, MAX(created_at) AS max_created_at
    FROM chat_messages
    GROUP BY chat_id
) AS cm
JOIN chats AS ch ON ch.id = cm.chat_id
ORDER BY cm.max_created_at DESC;```